How to override default content type in Cro::HTTP::Client?
I'm creating an object for making HTTP requests like this:
        $!ua = Cro::HTTP::Client.new(
            base-uri     => 'https://what.ever/api/',
            content-type => 'application/json'
        );

but one of the API endpoints requires using content-type: multipart/form-data instead.
Naively doing something like
        my $response = await $!ua.post(
            "add",
            content-type => 'multipart/form-data',
            body => [Cro::HTTP::Body::MultiPartFormData::Part.new(
                headers => [Cro::HTTP::Header.new(
                    name => 'content-type',
                    value => $mimetype
                )],
                name => $name,
                body-blob => $data,
            )]
        );

results in an error because both content types are concatenated:
    Could not parse media type 'application/json,multipart/form-data'

But how can I override the default content type here?
I've tried doing
        $!ua.content-type = '';
        LEAVE {
            $!ua.content-type = 'application/json';
        }

in the same function but this fails with
Cannot modify an immutable Str (application/json)

which I don't fully understand (why assigning an empty string works but not for the non-empty one?), but I guess this is not the right way to do it anyhow. But which one is?
I can just create another client, of course, but this seems a bit wasteful. And I can avoid specifying the default content type, but then I'd have to do it in all the other requests (of which there are a few), which is not great neither.

It seems like your issue centers on using Cro::HTTP::BodyParsers. But you can also call external parsers if you want, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/769560

Sorry, not sure why do you think the issue is due to body parsers when the problem is with the Content-Type header?

You could always use two clients. One for JSON and the other for multipart/form-data. You'd have to keep cookies synced between the two. It's as hack, but might be a workaround util something more elegant is found:
my $c1 = Cro::HTTP::Client.new: content-type => 'application/json';
my $c2 = Cro::HTTP::Client.new: content-type => 'multipart/form-data';


Thanks, this is what I ended up by doing, and it works, of course.

According to the Cro docs:
"If writing a client for a JSON API, it may become tedious to set the content type on every request. In this case, it can be set when constructing an instance of the client, and used by default (note that it will only be used if a body is set):"
# Configure with JSON content type.
my $client = Cro::HTTP::Client.new: content-type => 'application/json';

# And later get it added by default.
my %panda = name => 'Bao Bao', eats => 'bamboo';
my $resp = await $client.post: 'we.love.pand.as/pandas', body => %panda;

So according to the docs, all you have to do is omit the body argument in your post request, to unset the default content-type => 'application/json'.
Then by setting the request body, you can configure it to anything you want (e.g. content-type => 'multipart/form-data').
REFERENCE:
https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-client#Setting_the_request_body

Sorry, but I do need the body, as shown in the code above -- a multipart/form-data without body would be pretty useless.

The %panda argument is the default, which can omitted. Maybe you missed the statement, "...by setting the request body, you can configure it to anything you want... .

Sorry, I still don't understand what do you mean. If I omit the body, I don't post the correct body. If I do specify a body, I get the default content type header. Could you please give an example of sending a request with a body and without application/json content-type?
